# VBA Regular Expressions - Run-Time Error 91 when trying to replace characters in string

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am doing this task as part of a larger sub in order to massively reduce the workload for a different team.

I am trying to read in a string and use Regular Expressions to replace one-to-many spaces with a single space (or another character). At the moment I am using a local string, however in the main sub this data will come from an external .txt file. The number of spaces between elements in this .txt can vary depeneding on the row.

I am using the below code, and replacing the spaces with a dash. I have tried different variations and different logic on the below code, but always get "Run-time error '91': Object Variable or with clock variable not set" on line "c = re.Replace(s, replacement)"

After using breakpoints, I have found out that my RegularExpression (re) is empty, but I can't quite figure out how to progress from here. How do I replace my spaces with dashes? I have been at this problem for hours and spent most of that time on Google to see if someone has had a similar issue.

```
Sub testWC()

Dim s As String
Dim c As String
Dim re As RegExp

s = "hello      World"

Dim pattern As String
pattern = "\s+"
Dim replacement As String
replacement = "-"

c = re.Replace(s, replacement)
Debug.Print (c)

End Sub
```

**Extra information:** Using Excel 2010. Have successfully linked all my references (Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5". I was sucessfully able to replace the spaces using the vanilla "Replace" function, however as the number of spaces between elements vary I am unable to use that to solve my issue.

Ed: My .txt file is not fixed either, there are a number of rows that are different lengths so I am unable to use the MID function in excel to dissect the string either

Please help

Thanks,

J.H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting up the `RegExp` object correctly.

```
Dim pattern As String
pattern = "\s+" ' pattern is just a local string, not bound to the RegExp object!
```

You need to do this:

```
Dim re As RegExp
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\s+"    ' Now the pattern is bound to the RegExp object
re.Global = True      ' Assuming you want to replace *all* matches

s = "hello      World"
Dim replacement As String
replacement = "-"

c = re.Replace(s, replacement)
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank goodness, I have been at this for 4 hours now. Thank you very much, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the pattern inside your Regex object.  Right now, `re` is just a regex with no real pattern assigned to it.  Try adding in `re.Pattern = pattern` after you initialize your `pattern` string.

You initialized the pattern but didn't actually hook it into the Regex.  When you ended up calling `replace` it didn't know what it was looking for pattern wise, and threw the error.

Try also setting the `re` as a `New RegExp`.

```
Sub testWC()

Dim s As String
Dim c As String
Dim re As RegExp
Set re = New RegExp

s = "hello      World"

Dim pattern As String
pattern = "\s+"
re.Pattern = pattern
Dim replacement As String
replacement = "-"

c = re.Replace(s, replacement)
Debug.Print (c)

End Sub
```

Comment: I understand what you mean (thanks in part to Tim's reply). Tried your solution out of curiosity and am still faced with the same error. This time it occurs on line "re.Pattern = pattern".

For some reason, "re.Pattern" is replaced with "re.pattern" no matter how many times I try and fix it, so it may be a problem with that.

Regardless, thanks for your help